# Why is this regexp returning an empty item at the beginning of the array?

Tags: regex, arrays

I've got a javascript string I'm trying to split, but I'm getting an empty element at the beginning of the returned array, and I can't figure out why.

```
var split_in_el = in_el.split(/(#|\.|\[)/);
```

where split_in_el is either `first`,`#last`, or `[color:red]`.

the returned arrays I'm getting (in Node.js, but shouldn't matter) are

```
.first //split_in_el
[ '', '.', 'first' ]  //returned
#last //split_in_el
[ '', '#', 'last' ] //returned
[color:blue] //split_in_el
[ '', '[', 'color:blue]' ] //returned
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the issue.

Comment: It is really surprising that you got the result `[ '', '.', 'first' ]` from `first`, and `[ '', '[', 'color:blue]' ]` from `[color:red]`. I actually doubt it.

Comment: @sawa, if it is such a simple answer, than please answer it. Maybe I'm making a stupid mistake, but I don't see what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `split()` works in general, let's say we are splitting the following on the dot `.`:

```
Hello.World
     ^
----- -----
```

Then the returned array would be: `["Hello", "World"]`.

Now what if the previous line were like this:

```
    .World
    ^
  -- -----
```

Then we get an array like this: `["", "World"]`, the `split()` method returns everything before the dot `.` and everything after the `.`, nothing exists before the dot `.` here so it returns empty string `""`.

In a larger example:

```
.Hello.World.From.
```

It would return: `["", "Hello", "World", "From", ""]`.

Now the confusing part in your situation shouldn't be how you are getting the empty string, but rather how are you getting the character which you are splitting about in the resulting array.

For example, there is a dot `.` when you split around the dot `.` in `.first`, and there is a pound sign `#` when you split around the pound sign `#` in `#last`, etc ..

This can become obvious when you look at the [documentation of `split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit#Description) method:

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

The separator in your case is a regular expression `/(#|\.|\[)/` that matches *(or splits around)* either a dot `.`, pound sign `#` or a colon `:` inside a capturing group, so they are added to the resulting array.

```
/(#|\.|\[)/
 ^       ^
 ---------
 These parentheses are used to create the capturing group
```

You can solve this by converting the capturing group into a non-capturing one like this:

```
/(?:#|\.|\[)/
  ^^
Notice the syntax
```

Finally I want to add one thing: in situations like `.first` and `#last` you probably don't want to use `split()`, but rather [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Fexec) or [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch) to look for a particular match using a given pattern.

For example if you want to retrieve the word after a `.` character like `.first` then you can do:

```
var matches = ".first".match(/\.\w+/);
```